# Этимология слова "наложница"

Tags: этимология, значение-слов

Подскажите, пожалуйста, значение и происхождение слова "наложница".

Answer (score 4):

"На ложе". То есть, женщина для ложа. В общем, говоря иначе, для плотских утех.

Answer (score 0):

**нало́жница**
1. *истор*. пленница или крепостная, вынужденная стать любовницей;
2. *устар*. любовница, содержанка.

(Синонимы: кадынья, конкубина, метресса, любовница, наперсница, одалиска, пленница, рабыня, содержанка.
Словарь Даля: незаконная жена; служанка, убирающая постель; постельница.)

Составлено из ***на*** + **ложе**; от праслав. *lože, от кот. в числе прочего произошли: др.-русск., ст.-слав. *ложе*, русск., укр. *ло́же*, болг. *ло́же*( постель, матка, послед)... Вместе с *ложесна́* связано с *лежать*.

**[Наложницы в разных культурах](http://fb.ru/article/189973/nalojnitsa---eto-chem-otlichalis-nalojnitsyi-v-raznyih-kulturah)**